# Can a Video File Upload be retrieved via PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, forms, elementor

If I create a form with a simple "File Upload" input like this:

```html
<div class="elementor-field-type-upload elementor-field-group elementor-column elementor-field-group-dp_powercontrol elementor-col-100">
<label for="form-field-dp_powercontrol" class="elementor-field-label">Power Control</label>
<input type="file" name="form_fields[dp_powercontrol]" id="form-field-dp_powercontrol" class="elementor-field elementor-size-sm  elementor-upload-field" data-maxsize="250" data-maxsize-message="This file exceeds the maximum allowed size.">
</div>
<div class="elementor-field-type-upload elementor-field-group elementor-column elementor-field-group-dp_mechanicalfunctions elementor-col-100">
<label for="form-field-dp_mechanicalfunctions" class="elementor-field-label">Mechanical Functions</label>
<input type="file" name="form_fields[dp_mechanicalfunctions]" id="form-field-dp_mechanicalfunctions" class="elementor-field elementor-size-sm  elementor-upload-field" data-maxsize="250" data-maxsize-message="This file exceeds the maximum allowed size.">
</div>
<button type="submit" class="elementor-button elementor-size-sm">
<span>
<span class=" elementor-button-icon">
</span>
<span class="elementor-button-text">Send</span>
</span>
</button>
```

..for the purposes of this topic, let's just call the video upload FormSubmission.mp4 and the second one FormSubmission2.mp4. When these videos are uploaded, it gets posted into the WordPress Media Library. What I'd like to avoid is going into Elementor, manually creating a Video widget, and specifying the video attachment in the Media Library every time a .mp4 is uploaded.

If I create a blank page in Elementor, whether it be through a widget, a plugin, or a PHP Snippet / JS Code, is there a process/method in which I could use dynamic content to retrieve the video files that were just uploaded without having to select them by hand?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use webhooks of the upload form.
See the example here under "How can I integrate another service with webhook and field mapping? ":
https://elementor.com/help/form-widget-faq/

Make a webhook to move the files to a known location and read that location in another script